# How to embed VB to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to embed VB to asp.net so we could place our program on the net.

Comment: `VB` as what? the language? a windows application made in VB, what?

Answer (score 0):

Without an ActiveX control I don't mind you'll be able to do such strange thing! Web is Web, desktop is desktop, aren't they?

If you're thinking in just using an (X)HTML element and embed a Windows executable, no way: this doesn't exist.

Some articles that maybe are of your interest:

- http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson13/ (if this "VB program" is VB 6.0)
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dsandor/activexinnet11102005040748am/activexinnet.aspx (or if it's VB.NET)

By the way, I want to point to the fact that such program will only work in Microsoft Internet Explorer (don't mind to have something like this in Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera...).

Answer (score 0):

From what I've heard, I don't think this is truly possible. It may be easier to copy your code and modify into ASP.NET since VB is very similar.